# I bought a pair of tefillin -- help me understand the accompanying certificate?

Tags: tefilin

[image]Can someone tell me when this paper states? I don't know any Hebrew. I just want to know what the paper that came with pair of tefillin I bought states.

Comment: I don’t think MY should open itself up to being a translation service despite the fact that the article discussed is a Jewish item.

Comment: A belated mazel tov on your purchase! May they bring you many years of pleasure and kavannah while davenning.

Answer (score 10):

The first line with a checked options has:

> [x] New Tefillin  [] Used Tefillin

The next horizontal line indictes writing Style:

> [] Sepharadi / Yemenite [] Ashkenaz - Ar"i [x] Ashkenaz - Beis Yosef

The vertical checklist gives the quality:

> [x] Basic - Mehudar 
>   [ ] "small animal" - leather from sheep or goats
>   [ ] "small animal" one piece - the tefillin are made from a single piece of leather
>   [ ] "large" - leather from cows
>   [ ] "Miksha A/B" - single piece of "large animal" leather.

There is an empty line for special requests.

Results of the Kashrus check:

> [ ] pasul [ ] Kosher Bedieved - Kosher, but no so great [x] Kosher with no problems [ ] Mehudar - really nice

There is another empty line for comments from the one who checked the Tefillin.

> "This form is also a warranty"

Comment: Thank you for translating the text. It really helps.

Comment: It also mentions the name of the particular computer program used to check: "Tor" (a relatively common program for this purpose)